# Using Express to serve the contents of a JavaScript file through a route

Tags: javascript, express

I am relatively new to express and I would like to create a simple server that can be used to stream the contents of a JavaScript library I wrote through a route. The hope is to be able to us it in another project to be able to embed this library in a script tag like:

`<script type=“text/JavaScript” src=“https://my domain.com/js/v1”></script>`

Without having specify the file in the path.

Any good starting points or examples? I’ve only been able to put together some basic static hosting examples that still require the “foo.js” to be included in the path.

I’ve walked through a basic tutorial to host static assets but it still requires a full path to the asset.

Comment: Looks like a good starting point. I’ll give it a go. Thanks!